# Youtube scraping videos

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to gather information on the latest video released.
This code is ok, but it prints all information on all videos. How can I get the information on the latest video ONLY?
TY.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url="https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?user=USER"

html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

for i in soup.find_all("entry"):
    for title in i.find_all("title"):
        print(title.text)
    for link in i.find_all("link"):
        print(link["href"])
    for name in i.find_all("name"):
        print(name.text)
    for pub in i.find_all("published"):
        print(pub.text+"\n")
```

I need this info because i'm doing my own custom Discord bot that post a message if there is a new video online

OUTPUT

```
Hillbilly Cheapskate Is The Worst Kind....
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qy7mDjFn4TU
PewDiePie
2021-04-08T16:33:07+00:00

How much does Pewdiepie Make
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HORIiz_9Q4M
PewDiePie
2021-04-07T14:27:54+00:00

Pewdiepie Died (Felix Kjellberg Reacts)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WaP7nHQEV-o
PewDiePie
2021-04-06T16:55:37+00:00

I am Smarter than Reddit
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EONv6RzsCFo
PewDiePie
2021-04-05T16:51:25+00:00

ecc ecc ecc
```

Comment: Can you maybe show the list output of all videos?

Comment: Is this now printed as a string or as a list/dict?

Comment: each line is string

Comment: So you got it all printed as one string or as single strings and is it normally a string or are you converting it as a string? (Can you maybe just show how you did the printing?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in a limit using

```
soup.findAll('entry', limit=1)
```

you can find all other functions available [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs))